# Tomcat database connections leak

Tags: database, tomcat, connection, memory-leaks, pool

Hi We are using tomcat 6 and context.xml is like below

```
<Context>
   <Resource defaultAutoCommit="false" defaultReadOnly="false"
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    fairQueue="false" initialSize="${DBPool.initialPoolSize}"
    jdbcInterceptors="ConnectionState;StatementFinalizer"
    jmxEnabled="true" logAbandoned="false" maxActive="${DBPool.maxPoolSize}"
    maxIdle="30" maxWait="30000"
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="5000" minIdle="${DBPool.minPoolSize}"
    name="jdbc/BankDBPool" password="${DBPool.bankPassword}"
    removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
    testOnBorrow="false" testOnReturn="true"
    testWhileIdle="false" timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="5000"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    url="${DBPool.jdbcUrl}"
    factory="uk.co.xxxx.encryption.dbcp.DecryptingBasicDataSourceFactory"
    useEquals="false" username="${DBPool.bankUser}" validationInterval="30000" validationQuery="select 1 from dual" />
</Context>

DBPool.maxPoolSize=400
DBPool.minPoolSize=15
DBPool.initialPoolSize=15
```

The issue is we have to set maxPoolSize to very high as it is giving connection not available Exception. 
DB Monitor tool is showing the connections idle but seems they can not be reused. Traffic to this application is very low. Around 10000 hits in a day.

We are trying to figure out what might be an issue here.

All my service methods are all marked 
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = true or false)

DecryptingBasicDataSourceFactory only does job of returning datasource. 
We are using spring and hibernate.

Comment: Are you able to post the stacktrace for the 'connection not available exception'?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved. Apparently one of the method had @Transactional missing. Another change was reducing the batch-size in hibernate properties from 100 to 20. But mostly it was adding @Transactional which fixed the issue.